# Solving the Stress-energy-momentum tensor with metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Let's say I want to find an expression for $T_{00}$ in Einstein field equations given a particular metric. I need to find first $g_{00}$, which is not complicated to find, and $R_{00}$ which is actually quite tricky. I wondered if there was another way to solve for $R_{00}$ than to calculate first $\Gamma_{00}$ which is by itself quite long and then calculate find $R_{00}=d\Gamma_{00}^{m}/dx^{m}-d\Gamma_{0m}^{m}/dt+\Gamma_{00}^{m}\Gamma_{mn}^{n}-\Gamma_{0m}^{n}\Gamma_{0n}^{m}$.

Comment: A simpler way, as well.

Comment: Do $\Gamma^m_{nl}$ are the Christoffel symbols or the Ricci rotation coefficients?

Comment: No there is no other way. Either you define the metric and solve for the SE tensor or you define an SE tensor and solve for the metric. You can make the calculation part less taxing by using computers but to my knowledge, that is the only way to compute the Ricci and the SE tensor.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, I believe a software called Maple is widely used. I believe it can calculate for a given metric, the Riemann, Ricci and even Weyl tensors.